# how to detect bug on iOS8_beta4 webgl vertex shander sampler2d

Tags: webgl, detection, vertex-shader

on ios beta 4,ipad2, i did some check to see if the device support gpu particle simulation..

```
gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS) >= 1
!!gl.getExtension( 'OES_texture_float' )
```

they both say yes, but things dont really work...

I wanna know how to detect this kind of bug...
so that i can fall back to other things to show...

webgl preview and src:
https://googledrive.com/host/0B2CX8zXCqhScelpNMkpSX1pmRHM

screenshots:
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2CX8zXCqhScR0d2SExtZm9EWDA

---

I use this to detect iOS 8 beta4 and before....
is there any better way to detect and fallback?

```
    if (
        navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/)
    ){
        var usrA= navigator.userAgent;
        var info = usrA.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || [];
        if (parseFloat(info[2],10) <= 9537){
            check.gpuSim = false;
        }
    }
```

thx for reading this >v<~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking by `userAgent` for anything whatsoever in HTML/JavaScript [is an anti-pattern](https://www.google.com/?#q=useragent+bad+practice).

The correct way for his case is to check if you can render to a floating point texture (something that's usually needed for particle simulations). To test if you can render to floating point textures you need to create a framebuffer, attach a floating point texture, then check if it's complete.

```
var gl = someCanvasElement.getContext("experimental-webgl");
var ext = gl.getExtension("OES_texture_float");
if (!ext) {
    alert("no OES_texture_float");
    return;
}
```

now you can create and render with floating point textures. The next thing to do is see if you can render to floating point textures.

```
var tex = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, width, height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, null);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

var fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
gl.bindFrameBuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex, 0);

var status = gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER);
if (status != gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
  alert("can not render to floating point textures");
  return;
}
```

Also, if you use a depth or stencil attachment when rendering to that floating point texture you need to attach that as well before checking if it's complete.

Comment: Thx for the help! The detection for gl.FLOAT texture works! amazing!  

Then I try to use gl.FLOAT texture, the particle fly weirdly in gl.FLOAT texture, but well in gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE. This should be my bad for the shader code because i just learn it in a relatively short time and still improving it. >v<~  

And when I use the same detection method, but change the texture from gl.FLOAT to gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE on iPad iOS8Beta4, it cannot detect failure of support that kind of texture. it can only detect failure for gl.FLOAT texture. How can i detect that failure support on iPad?
  
thx for reading~

Comment: https://github.com/wonglok/WebGLWidget/blob/improvements/app/scripts/webgl/core.js#L524

Comment: `gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE`+`gl.RGBA` or some other format? `gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE`+`gl.RGBA` is required to work by WebGL. If it doesn't that's a bug that will hopefully be fixed before iOS8 ships. In fact iOS itself would not even run if `gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE`+`gl.RGBA` was not renderable. Maybe I don't understand your question. Are you setting the filtering? Some GPUs require filtering to be off (like I show above) while rendering to a texture.

Comment: Thx for the quick reply. The gl.RGBA+gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE texture for sampler2d in vertex shader works on android chrome + desktop chrome&firefox&safari, BUT NOT ios8 beta4.

Also, ios8 does not support floating point texture.

i want to try to detect sampler2d in vertexshader bug in ios8 beta4.

Comment: So you're saying with `gl.RGBA`+`gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE` render buffer attachment iOS8 beta4 claims it can render (you get `gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE` from `gl.checkRenderbufferStatus()`) but that you still can't render to the texture? If so, then make a 1x1 pixel texture, render to it, call `gl.readPixels`. If you don't get the color you expect then you know it doesn't work.

Comment: I found out that without gl_PointSize it breaks on iOS but works on other platform. Now it's fixed after adding it to the vertex shader. Thanks for your help! I learned a lot during this process. :) do you have a paypal donate button to buy you a cup of coffee? @v@